# adding custom controls in design mode

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I made a custom user control consisting of a checkbox and few textboxes and some code. I discovered it shows up in the component toolbox in design mode but when i drag it to the project, it gives me an error thats something like "failed to create component" "constructor not found" and a bunch of statements around something called binding.

I wasnt originally planning to use it in design mode but since i now know its a possibility, id be interested if its possible to make it design mode compatible somehow?

EDIT:
the control components are designed in the design mode, they are 
"cCheckbox" - an on/off switch 
"cInterval" - a textbox only allowing numbers
"cUnit" - a dropdown combobox with units from second to a day
the purpose of the control is to provide a user modifiable timer that generates tick events for another part of the program

```
Public Class ucTimer1
  Public Event Tick(time As Date)
  Private WithEvents t As New Timer With {.Interval = 1000}
  Private lastTick As DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
  Private interval As TimeSpan
  Public persistent As Boolean = True
  Public sDat As New List(Of Object)

Public Sub New(Optional sDat() As Object = Nothing)
    InitializeComponent()
    turnOff()
    AddHandler cCheck.CheckedChanged, Sub() If cCheck.Checked Then turnOn() Else turnOff()
    cUnit.SelectedIndex = 1

    If Not sDat Is Nothing Then
        lastTick = sDat(0)
        cInterval.Text = sDat(1)
        cUnit.SelectedIndex = sDat(2)
        cCheck.Checked = sDat(3)
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub textFilter(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles cInterval.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar <> Convert.ToChar(8) Then
        If Not "0123456789".Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString) Or cInterval.Text.Length > 2 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub turnOff()
    If cCheck.Checked = True Then cCheck.Checked = False
    cCheck.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
    cInterval.Enabled = False
    cUnit.Enabled = False
    cIntervalBackground1.BackColor = BackColor
    cIntervalBackground2.BackColor = BackColor
    save()
End Sub
Public Sub turnOn()
    If cCheck.Checked = False Then cCheck.Checked = True
    cInterval.Enabled = True
    cUnit.Enabled = True
    cIntervalBackground1.BackColor = cInterval.BackColor
    cIntervalBackground2.BackColor = cInterval.BackColor
    evalInterval()
End Sub
Private Sub evalInterval() Handles cInterval.TextChanged, cUnit.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim seconds As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(cInterval.Text, seconds) Then seconds = 0

    Select Case cUnit.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            seconds *= 1
        Case 1
            seconds *= 60
        Case 2
            seconds *= 3600
        Case 3
            seconds *= 86400
        Case Else
            seconds *= 0
    End Select

    If seconds < 1 Then
        cCheck.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
        t.Enabled = False
    Else
        interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds)
        cCheck.ForeColor = Color.Green
        t.Enabled = True
    End If
    save()
End Sub
Private Sub ticker() Handles t.Tick
    If interval = Nothing Then Return
    If DateTime.Now - lastTick > interval Then
        lastTick = DateTime.Now
        RaiseEvent Tick(DateTime.Now)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub save()
    If Not persistent Then Return
    sDat.Clear()
    sDat.Add(lastTick)
    sDat.Add(cInterval.Text)
    sDat.Add(cUnit.SelectedIndex)
    sDat.Add(cCheck.Checked)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you posts your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add new constructor without parameter and change the original construction like this

**Because VB.Net requires "Public Sub New()" constructor during design mode**

```
....Codes before this

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    turnOff()
    AddHandler cCheck.CheckedChanged, Sub() If cCheck.Checked Then turnOn() Else turnOff()
    cUnit.SelectedIndex = 1
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal sDat() As Object)
    InitializeComponent()
    turnOff()
    AddHandler cCheck.CheckedChanged, Sub() If cCheck.Checked Then turnOn() Else turnOff()
    cUnit.SelectedIndex = 1
    If Not sDat Is Nothing Then
        lastTick = sDat(0)
        cInterval.Text = sDat(1)
        cUnit.SelectedIndex = sDat(2)
        cCheck.Checked = sDat(3)
    End If
End Sub

......Rest of your Code
```

Answer (score 0):

in your constructor, check whether it's design mode, run your specific code only it's not in design mode, something like:

```
Public Sub New(Optional sDat() As Object = Nothing)
    InitializeComponent()

    If Not Me.DesignMode Then
        turnOff()
        AddHandler cCheck.CheckedChanged, Sub() If cCheck.Checked Then turnOn() Else turnOff()
        cUnit.SelectedIndex = 1

        If Not sDat Is Nothing Then
            lastTick = sDat(0)
            cInterval.Text = sDat(1)
            cUnit.SelectedIndex = sDat(2)
            cCheck.Checked = sDat(3)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

made the change and rebuild your solution (to force it to take effect), then try it again in design mode.